# continuous mapping from a trivial topological space

Tags: general-topology, continuity

**Definition**:

\begin{equation*}
    f \textit{ is continuous }\Leftrightarrow \textit{ for all open subsets  }B \subseteq Y \textit{ is } f^{-1}(B) \textit{ open in } X
\end{equation*}

Just to be sure on this:

If I map from any non-trivial topological space to a trivial topological space: $(X,\tau)\rightarrow (Y,\sigma)$, that the mapping has to be continuous. So **every** mapping is than continuous.

My proof: I will have $f^{-1}(\emptyset)\in \tau$ and $f^{-1}(Y)=X\in \tau$

Question 1: Is it true that $f^{-1}(Y)=X$ and why?

Now the opposite:

If I map from any trivial topological space to a non-trivial topological space: $(X,\tau)\rightarrow (Y,\sigma)$, that the mapping is **never** continuous.

This is because $\sigma$ has always open sets different fom $X$ and $\emptyset$.

Question 2: Is this part right?

I found this already: [Continuous functions with trivial topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737808/continuous-functions-with-trivial-topology)

This is the exact question I have but I don't see why $f$ should be onto (surjective)? Bacause we are operating with $f^{-1}$?

Comment: Look at a constant map from a trivial to a non-trivial space?

Comment: But I have different Spaces $X\neq Y$?

Comment: I did not take $X=Y$. It is impossible to have two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that no function from $X$ to $Y$ is continuous.

Comment: In this case I have $f^{-1}(c)=2^X$ with $c\in Y$. Than $f^{-1}(X)=f^{-1}(\emptyset )=\emptyset$. I think I see what you mean. Is this the only continuous function? How can I prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f^{-1}[Y]$ is the *pre-image* of a set under $f$, it's not about an inverse map. I prefer the notion with brackets over the one with braces for this notion.

If $f: X \to Y$ is any function and $B \subseteq Y$ then $f^{-1}[B] = \{x \in X \mid f(x) \in B\}$ is just the set of points of the domain that map into $B$. So if $B=Y$, by *definition* of a function from $X$ to $Y$, all $f(x) \in Y$ and so $f^{-1}[Y]=X$ follows.

So if $f$ is constant with value $c$, $f^{-1}[B]=X$ if $c \in B$ and $\emptyset$ otherwise. So always open in $X$ regardless of what topology $X$ or $Y$ have.

As an afterhought: suppose that $X$ has the trivial topology $\{\emptyset,X\}$, and if $f$ is *not* constant so there are $x,x'$ in $X$ such that $f(x) \neq f(x')$. If in $Y$ there is an open set $O$ that contains just one of the points $\{f(x), f(x')\}$ then $f$ cannot be continuous as $f^{-1}[O]$ is non-empty (it contains $x$ or $x'$) and also not equal to $X$ (it misses $x$ or $x'$; the other one), so $f^{-1}[O]$ cannot be open. But e.g. $X=\{1,2,3\}$ in the trivial topology to $Y=\{1,2,3\}$ in the topology $\{\emptyset, \{2,3\}, Y\}$ has a non-constant continuous function (defined by $f(1)=2, f(2)=3, f(3)=2$, which has $f^{-1}[\emptyset] = \emptyset, f^{-1}[Y] =X, f^{-1}[\{2,3\}] = X$ so is continuous)).

So it's *not* true that a trivial topology only has constant maps to non-trivial $Y$, it will depend on the topology of $Y$.

In fact, let $I(2)$ be the space $\{0,1\}$ in the indiscrete/ trivial topology.

> $Y$ is $T_0$ iff every continuous $f: I(2) \to Y$ is constant

Proof: If $Y$ is $T_0$ and $f$ is a function from $I(2)$ to $Y$ that is non-constant then $f(0) \neq f(1)$ and so by $T_0$-ness there is an open set $O$ in $Y$ such that $\{f(0),f(1)\} \cap O$ has one member, say $f(0)$ WLOG. Then $f^{-1}[O]=\{0\}$ is not open in $I(2)$. So $f$ is not continuous.

If we assume the mapping property, we can show that $Y$ is $T_0$: suppose $Y$ is not $T_0$. Then there are two points $y_1\neq y_2$ in $Y$ such that for every open set $O$ in $Y$ we have $y_1 \in O \land y_2 \in O$ or $y_1 \notin O \land y_2 \notin O$; we cannot separate them by an open set. But that implies that the map $f$ sending $0$ to $y_1$ and $1$ to $y_2$ is continuous, as $f^{-1}[O]=\emptyset$ or $=I(2)$ depending on which is the case for $O$. And $f$ is non-constant, so that would contradict the mapping property. So $Y$ is $T_0$.

So in topological category theory we could say that the $T_0$ spaces are the $I(2)$-co-connected spaces in $\mathbf{Top}$, or some such term. Connected spaces are $D(2)$-connected (where $D(2)=\{0,1\}$ in the discrete topology), as is classical (all continuous functions *into* $D(2)$ are constant).

Comment: Thank you, makes all sense. But I have still a bad feeling because I don't know if the constant function is the only one that is continuous in that case...

Comment: @Averroes2 I added an example with $X$ trivial and non-constant map.

Comment: Thanks, thats a good one. Can you see what conditions Y has to meet?

Comment: @Averroes2 $Y$ must have a subspace that is not $T_0$, if you look at the argument before the example.

Comment: Does this mean it can have only 3 open sets?

Comment: @Averroes2 No, that was just the easiest way to make a quick example. If $Y$ is $T_0$ all continuous functions from a trivial $X$ into $Y$ are constant. If $X$ is not $T_0$ examples of non-constant such $f$ will exist.

Comment: In your last comment you mean $Y$ is not $T_0$"? If $Y$ is not $T_0$ that the function cannot be surjective?

Comment: @Averroes2 see the theorem I added.

Answer (score 1):

1. $f^{-1}(Y)=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in Y\}=X$.
2. *Every* constant map is continuous. So, in particular, if $\tau$ is the trivial topology on $X$ and $\sigma$ is some topology on $Y$, then there are continuous maps from $(X,\tau)$ into $(Y,\sigma)$.

Comment: Thank you, for (1): This was a confusion regarding the definition, now it's clear. For (2): Is this the only continuous function in that case?

Comment: Usually, yes. But if, for instance, $\sigma$ is also the trivial topology, then *any* map from $X$ into $Y$ is continuous.